# weird behavior Golang app crashing when running through Supervisor

Tags: go, ubuntu-14.04, supervisord

Hello my  Go app keeps crashing and restart each time I run it through supervisor but when I run it on the terminal it's running without crashing, I don't know where I start or on what should I search any help or hint to start with?

P.S: logs always empty

edit: it's run for 1 or 2 min and crashing not crashing immediately

Comment: Questions seeking debugging help ("why isn't this code working?") must include the desired behavior, a specific problem or error and the shortest code necessary to reproduce it in the question itself. Questions without a clear problem statement are not useful to other readers.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have several golang servers running just fine under supervisord ... its probably some permission thing ... in your supervisor config file replace launching your golang binary with full path to reach this shell script

```
#!/bin/bash

for i in {1..3}; do

    echo here I am inside loop with counter $i

    sleep 2
done

echo now exiting from loop
```

its just something to run as a deamon for a few seconds ... if that runs OK is the OS where you compile your go code same as where your supervisord is running ?

Comment: it was permission problem that I'm not able to find any logs, so once I fixed it, I found the main problem and fixed it, Thank you